# What is the build order for the 3RR+lings rush?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

I've seen some posts about a 3RR+lings which is supposed to be similar to the 7RR, but with only 3 roaches and speedlings, allowing easier worker harassment once the roaches breach the wall-off.

What is the exact build order to use for this, and what should you look for when scouting to see if you should perform this build? (or cancel it)

Comment: I don't know exact answer for this question. But I can tell you how I'm searching for strategies: 1. Check the [strategy page](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Strategy) on liquipedia. It's a great place where you can get info about starcraft 2 stuff. 2. google 3. If you didn't find BO yet then try to use [scbuildorder](http://code.google.com/p/scbuildorder/downloads/list) tool. Don't forget to check how many drones you'll have at end - program tends to leave you with sick economy (for sake of 10 seconds sometimes) after target is achieved.

Comment: and here is a link to BO at liquipedia http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/3_Roach_Rush_Speedling_all-in_(vs._Protoss)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I should warn you, this is an extremely poor build (very cheesy), with little or no chance of winning.  It hopes to catch your opponent unaware.

The build itself works something like the following:

- 13 Gas
- 13 Pool
- Queen
- 15 Roach Warren
- 17 Metabolic Boost

Its a derivation of the old 14 Gas/14 Pool builds, except that you go for a very early Roach Warren, don't build more than 15 Drones, and all in around ~3:45.  You use your Roaches like a Baneling bust with lings to back up

I really don't recommend it, its largely inferior to the kind of pressure you can bring with a 15 Expand Roach/Ling build at the 6 minute mark.  What's even worse it teaches you very bad habits (late or no expansion) and actually is amazingly weak against any standard play.

Comment: Thanks, you see people talking about builds on forums and if you aren't familiar with exactly what they are talking about its a bit confusing!